# missing years - replace with empty row

Tags: postgresql

I am tying to retrieve some data and it is as below:

| id | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 200 |
| 1 | 2016 | 3000 |
| 1 | 2018 | 500 |
| 2 | 2010 | 455 |
| 2 | 2015 | 678 |
| 2 | 2020 | 100 |

as you can see some years are missing - I would like to add the rows with missing years, null for column value and I want to do it per specific ids - any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to show missing years in a particular range, like the lowest to the highest for that id, or the lowest to the highest for the whole table, or some other range?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `GENERATE_SERIES()` with a left join do expand the missing years. For example:

```
select x.id, x.y, t.value
from (select id, generate_series(min(year), max(year)) as y from t group by id) x
left join t on t.id = x.id and t.year = x.y
```

Result:

```
 id  y     value 
 --- ----- ----- 
 1   2015  200   
 1   2016  3000  
 1   2017  null  
 1   2018  500   
 2   2010  455   
 2   2011  null  
 2   2012  null  
 2   2013  null  
 2   2014  null  
 2   2015  678   
 2   2016  null  
 2   2017  null  
 2   2018  null  
 2   2019  null  
 2   2020  100
```